# Array element splicing characters

Tags: ios

In addition to the "traversal" and "recursion" methods, how to achieve this function?
example:`@[@"20",@"50",@"100"] ->  @[@"20X",@"50X",@"100X"]`

Comment: "In addition to the "traversal" and "recursion" methods"? What did you try? What's your issue exactly? That seems to be Objective-C code, is Swift allowed? Could you clarify? What's your aim?

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = ["20","50","100"]
array = array.map({$0 + "X"})
```

You can use something like this to do your function.